# ¿Cómo muevo los botones de un Navbar en Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Estoy aprendiendo HTML CSS y Bootstrap y estoy armando una web. Necesito que el botón de nombre quede alineado a la izquierda y los otro cuatro botones alineados a la derecha, uno próximo al otro obviamente, y no puedo lograrlo. Es una NavBar simple.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nombre</a>
        <a id="navbar-facebook" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i</a>
        <a id="navbar-instagram" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a id="navbar-twitter" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a id="navbar-login" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Login</button></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `d-flex` de bootstrap para eso ([Documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)).

Para alinear el primer elemento a la izquierda puedes agregar la clase `me-auto` (Margin end)

Agregué también la clase `pe-2` (Padding end 2) a los botones de `FontAwesome` para que no se vieran pegados uno al otro, si los deseas juntos elimina eso del ejemplo

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex">
          <a class="navbar-brand me-auto" href="#">Nombre</a>
          <a id="navbar-facebook" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-square fa-lg pe-2"></i></a>
          <a id="navbar-instagram" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-lg pe-2"></i></a>
          <a id="navbar-twitter" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-lg pe-2"></i></a>
          <a id="navbar-login" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Login</button></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Veadma, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: ya la acepté, pero me dice que los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Veadma, ah, eso es porque en lugar de aceptar la respuesta votaste positivamente, entre las dos flechas (Arriba y abajo) hay un símbolo ✓, ese es el que hay que oprimir, todo el mundo puede aceptar respuestas aún con cuenta nueva

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias!